# Build process template already exists

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-process-template

I cannot select a new build process template while editing a TFS build definition. It's showing the below error while selecting a new template file...!

---

Microsoft Visual Studio

---

Team Foundation Error

TF277000: A build process template for '$/Project_Name/BuildTemplates/ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml' already exists for team project Project_Name. You cannot create another build process template for the same file. Use the existing one instead.

---

OK

---

Error is showing like template is already existing but it is not listing in build process file dropdown to select.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please delete TFS cache on that client machine, delete folder: C:\Users\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache (assume you're working with TFS2013, adjust with the template file you're using: ReleaseDefaultTemplate.**11.1**.xaml). After the cache folder is deleted, restart VS and see whether the ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml file is under the Build process file dropdown list.

If delete cache folder still doesn't work, please try create a new workspace to map to that server, and create a new build definition.